# Implementing Google API search from geonames

Tags: java, android, api, google-maps, geonames

I have been following a great tutorial that allows a user to input a postcode, then a ListView displays places around the globe that match the postcode. Once an address from the populated ListView is clicked its position is shown by a marker on the mapView.

I have worked through this tutorial and have been getting to grips with the HTTP webservices. At the moment the code is using the online service from 'geonames' database to query the supplied postalcode **I want to now implement Google API into my code to search for supermarkets.**

The geonames uses a JSON response from the supplied postal code in the following format:

```
{"postalCodes":[{"adminName2":"El Paso","adminCode2":"041","adminCode1":"CO","postalCode":"80907","countryCode":"US","lng":-104.817034,"placeName":"Colorado Springs","lat":38.876001,"adminName1":"Colorado"}]}
```

The above string is from a postal code of '80907'.

This is the the string URL for geonames:

```
private static final String GEONAME_RESTURL 
    = "http://api.geonames.org/postalCodeSearchJSON?maxRows=8&username=demo&postalcode=";
```

I have read the Google API documentation and have found the following 'nearby search request'search string:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere
```

Here is the code returning the postal code matches:

```
    DataWrapper wrap = new DataWrapper();
wrap = wrap.fromJson(responseString);
return wrap.postalCodes;
```

How can I find from this the returned JSON search string as seen above with the geoname result for the Google search string for supermarkets?

I realize I can fix the search radius to a specified number but I want to receive the matches for my search string to list the supermarkets.

Hoping I have been clear enough with this question!.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I managed to solve this by simply using geonames API. Im not sure if its as complete as Google API, but well worth alook with its registration.